# Когда использовать RadioButton, а когда ComboBox?

Tags: gui, ui, ux

Не могу понять зачем нужен RadioButton, если есть ComboBox ?

Что нельзя сделать с помощью ComboBox то что можно сделать с помощью RadioButton ?

Comment: С CheckBox все понятно, там может быть множественный выбор.

Comment: Для выбора с помощью RadioButton-а достаточно просто нажать на область, покрывающую радиокнопку и подпись к ней. ComboBox же требует более тонкой работы мышью и большего числа нажатий. То есть ComboBox — это компромиссное, но не идеальное решение для выбора из большого количества элементов; иными словами, RadioButton нужен для удобства пользователя.

Comment: Как пример. Вы когда-нибудь тесты на компьютере проходили? Там часто варианты ответов именно радиокнопками выбираются (если в задании требуется только один вариант ответа). Представьте теперь то же самое, но с выпадающими списками. Удобно будет? Если тест ещё и на время, пользователи вас проклянут за ComboBox.

Answer (score 0):

Радио батон когда несколько простых ответов. Комбо бокс когда ответы сложные или их много.

По сложности ответов выбор есть момент когда ответ не помещается в строку и занимает абзац - такой вариант тоже удобен с радио кнопкой.

К радиокнопке можно присоединить картинку, а к комбо боксу  "свой вариант ответв"